# How to join a data frame in a SQLite database with another data frame?

Tags: sql, r

I have a data.frame with many columns in a SQLite database (df in my example).

I'd like to update (or join) this data frame with a table that is in my R environment and not in SQLite (df2 in my example).

```r
library(RSQLite)
con <- DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), ":memory:")

df <- data.frame(
  code= c("A", "B"),
  var2 = c(10, 5),
  var3 = c(NA, NA)
)

DBI::dbWriteTable(con, "df", df)

# In my R global environment
df2 <- data.frame(
  code= c("A", "B"),
  var3 = c(8, 6)
)
```

Expected output :

```r
df <- data.frame(
  code= c("A", "B"),
  var2 = c(10, 5),
  var3 = c(8, 6)
)
```

Of course, I want to update the df table in the SQLite database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a temporary table:

```r
DBI::dbWriteTable(con, "df2", df2,temporary=T)

DBI::dbExecute(con,"UPDATE df SET var3 = (SELECT var3 FROM df2 WHERE code = df.code)")
#> [1] 2

DBI::dbReadTable(con,"df")
#>   code var2 var3
#> 1    A   10    8
#> 2    B    5    6
```

Comment: Thanks Waldi ! Is there a way of obtaining the same result without having to specify the name of the var3 column (i.e. by finding the column that is common to df and df2)?

Comment: @DamienDotta, I don't think this possibility exists in SQL syntax : you need to specify the join column.

Comment: Ok thanks what about joining with code column ?

Comment: I guess this is what is done: joining code with code

Comment: I just want to avoid to write multiple colums names var3, var4 ... joining the tables